# how to set Authentication setting data? VPN Mac OS Programatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, osx-yosemite, vpn, system-configuration

i am using this https://github.com/halo/macosvpn. Code run successfully and create new network but it's not showing Authentication Setting data which i Password e.g Shared Secret.

```
- (CFDictionaryRef) L2TPPPPConfig {
CFStringRef keys[4] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
CFStringRef vals[4] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
CFIndex count = 0;

keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPCommRemoteAddress;
vals[count++] = (__bridge CFStringRef)self.endpoint;

keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPAuthName;
vals[count++] = (__bridge CFStringRef)self.username;

keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPAuthPassword;
vals[count++] = (__bridge CFStringRef)self.serviceID;

keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPAuthPasswordEncryption;
vals[count++] = kSCValNetPPPAuthPasswordEncryptionKeychain;

return CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&vals, count, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

[image]

Furthermore Server Address and Account Name set Successfully. i

Comment: Have you found the solution for the issue? I am stuck in here too.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines look very suspicious:

```
keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPAuthPassword;
vals[count++] = (__bridge CFStringRef)self.serviceID;
```

Shouldn't that second line be something like:  "`self.password`"?

serviceID is something totally different than a password.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, hmm i know but Actually when you follow the Example then you get an idea why serviceID pass. in Example you will see the config Object pass to Keychain Items, the main issue is when we apply            'keys[count] = kSCPropNetPPPAuthPasswordEncryption;
vals[count++] = kSCValNetPPPAuthPasswordEncryptionKeychain; '   then our password not show.

Comment: where is the example you are referring to (is it somewhere in the https://github.com/halo/macosvpn project)?

Comment: yes i am using his project Classes. VPNServiceConfig.m you will see all configuration setting. i modify the code and call from Application.